# Yarn on Chrome: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: reactjs, yarnpkg

I have a working yarn react project on a local machine.

```
yarn start
```

Works, yields a website that renders on the local host.

I have a server that was running the same project.  However, I stopped the running website, and restarted with the following commands:

```
yarn install 
yarn run build
yarn run prod
```

And I get the following error when accessing the website through chrome (on the production server):

```
Ucaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

---

What I am trying to do is diagnose where the problems could be arising. To summarize:

> 1) the project runs on the local machine (mac osx) with `yarn start`
>
> 2) I place the project on the linux box, install, build and run and everything seems to be sending to chrome; however, chrome yields this error

I am not sure where the problem could be. Localizing it to a set of possible problems would, I think, make it easy to solve (or ask better questions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error typically happens when you are getting a HTML page for a `<script>` tag `src`'s address.

Open the URLs of the scripts each on a different tab (or check the network tab of the developer tools), those URLs are probably returning a 404 (or some other error code) and a HTML error page.

So your code tries to parse those HTML error pages as JavaScript code, thus yielding that error.

It gets `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`  because it tries to parse the HTML content (e.g. `<html> ...`) as JavaScript code.

For a **demo**, run the snippet below and see the error at the console.

```html
<script type=text/javascript src=https://stackoverflow.com></script>
Check the console: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <"
```

Comment: could this be caused by the server config? (for instance, nginx?)

Comment: Yes, certainly. It mostly depends on what the should-be-script HTML page is returning. Sometimes it's just a typo in the path, or a file you forgot to upload.

Comment: seems like it is misinterpreting the build js file as if it is a stylesheet.  Could this be a build configuration issue?

Comment: Could be. What makes you think that?

Comment: Ok, so I am looking at the files you mentioned.  First thing that gets downloaded to browser is the index.  The index lists two build files `<link href="/build/app-buildid.css" rel="stylesheet"/>` and `<script src="/build/app-buildid.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`, only chrome seems to try to interpret the `.js` file incorrectly, marking it with a red line when I inspect it.  

Beneath the unexpected token error, I have `Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: ".../build/app-buildid.css` (this one is a warning).

Comment: meanwhile, locally, when I inspect the same area, I just have an `app.js` file in the build folder, and everything works as expected. So I am guessing that something is wrong in the build (maybe a version error or something?)

Comment: Maybe the file is being served directly from the `build` folder, meaning the prefix `build` should not be necessary.